# WebRTC React Native gives exception on IOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webrtc, react-native-webrtc

i am using webRTC for implementing real time connection in my React Native app , i am getting the following error when the participant join from ios side.
"react-native-webrtc": "1.89.1"
"react-native": "0.63.3"

[image]

[image]

**how can i solve or ignore this error?**